# How to assign values with foreach?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I have trouble to assign values with `\foreach`. Can somebody help me? The following code is wrong. The purpose is to asing the values: `\lx1=1`, `\ly1=2`, `\lz1=3`, for example.

```
\foreach \x/\y in {\lx1/1,\ly1/2,\lz1/3}
{%
\def\x{\y}
\x{\y}
{
```

Comment: Do you want to assign values to `\lx1`, `\ly1` and `\lz1` *before* entering `\foreach`? Moreover, you cannot use macros as-is with numbers in it.

Answer (score 12):

There are several reasons, why this does not work:

- `\lx1` is not a command name, it consists of the command `\lx`, followed by digit `1`.
  Either replace `1` by a letter or the usage is a little more complex via `\csname`.
- `\x` and `\y` contain the x and y values, the definition of `\x` defines `\x`, not the macro inside and `\y` whill change with every loop. `\expandafter` expands a macro one level:

  ```
  \expandafter\def\x{...}
  ```

  Doing the same with `\y` requires lots of more `\expandafter`, therefore using `\let`
  is easier here.
- `\foreach` puts the loop body inside groups, thus local definitions will be lost.
  This can be solved by global definitions.

Example:

```
\usepackage{pgffor}

\foreach \x/\y in {\lxA/1,\lyA/2,\lzA/3}
{%
  \global\expandafter\let\x\y
}
```

Or with `\lx1` as macro:

```
\foreach \x/\y in {\lx1/1,\ly1/2,\lz1/3}
{%
  \begingroup
    \escapechar=-1 % suppresses backslash with \string
    \global\expandafter\let
    \csname \expandafter\string\x\endcsname\y
  \endgroup
}

\typeout{\expandafter\string\csname lx1\endcsname:
  \expandafter\meaning\csname lx1\endcsname}
```

**Addition for the fans of `\expandafter`:**

`\gdef` can be used instead of `\global\let` by using additional `\expandafter`:

```
\foreach \x/\y in {\lxA/1,\lyA/2,\lzA/3}
{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \gdef\expandafter\x\expandafter{\y}%
}

\typeout{\string\lxA: \meaning\lxA}

\foreach \x/\y in {\lx1/1,\ly1/2,\lz1/3}
{%
  \begingroup
    \escapechar=-1 % suppresses backslash with \string
    \expandafter\gdef
    \csname \expandafter\string\x\expandafter\endcsname
    \expandafter{\y}%
  \endgroup
}

\typeout{\expandafter\string\csname lx1\endcsname:
  \expandafter\meaning\csname lx1\endcsname}
```

As can be seen, the version with `\let` is more efficient and elegant.

Comment: Is it possible to make the same thing but using `\def` (or `\gdef`) and with each value of `\y` defined as `{some TeX code...}`? You just say it requires "_lots of `\exandafter`_"...

Comment: Thanks for your addition (Am I really a fan of `\expandafter`? ;-)).

Comment: I'll take the first solution. It's simple and clear. Thanks Heiko.